# Make any number of columns automatically populate and `auto-fill` the width of grid in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to auto-fill columns, any number from 2 to 4. I need the total column widths to fill the width of the grid for the 2, 3, or 4 possible columns.

But when I try code I see in SO solutions and tutorial pages like from [a CSS Tricks page](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/), they describe auto-filling something like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

But when I do it in Chrome, it says `invalid property value`.

HTML is something like:

```
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="some-column"></div>
    <div class="some-column"></div>
    <div class="some-column"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make any number of columns automatically populate and fill the width of my grid in Chrome?

Comment: The CSS You have is correct. What is the HTML you are working with?

Comment: Updated to show about what my HTML is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. Instead of `auto-fill` you need `auto-fit`.

Note however that this will NOT restrict the number of columns to just 4. It will create as many columns it needs to fit into the allowed width.

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  ;
}

.some-column {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="some-column"></div>
  <div class="some-column"></div>
  <div class="some-column"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="some-column"></div>
  <div class="some-column"></div>
</div>

<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="some-column"></div>
  <div class="some-column"></div>
  <div class="some-column"></div>
  <div class="some-column"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I typically use this:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
```

Chrome does support *grid-template-columns*, so you probably have a syntax error. Post your code and I could probably help more.

Comment: You're right. The code is valid. There was a typo. But now I see the solution doesn't work. It doesn't fill the grid...

Comment: can you post your CSS too?